# Laravel/socialite Composer package 5.6 or 5.7

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

I'm starting to install the laravel/socialite. I have the ***Laravel 5.6*** installed, so should I use `composer require laravel/socialite "^3.2.0"` based on the documentation from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite or can I use `composer require laravel/socialite` based on the https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/socialite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Laravel 5.6 then I think you should install
`composer require laravel/socialite "^3.2.0"`
If you use `composer require laravel/socialite` you can get an error, and this command trying to install version 4.0 which is not supported in Laravel 5.6